# Android sdk errors new developer

Tags: java, android, sdk

Guys I'm a new android developer. I am having a really hard time trying to get some of my apps to work. What is this error ?

**Logcat error**

[image]

Comment: please check link image in the question

Comment: Frist I would like to encourage you to edit your Question in way so that we can see your code (where it could be wrong) and log of your exception and a clear definition of what you trying to archive. Only in that way we will be able to help you out properly.

Comment: LOL, i got over 41k of red lines of code. how am i supposed to upload it all here, when i need to indent every line or it wont let me post?

Comment: top right corner of logcat, instead of no filter try show only selected application

Comment: ok guys i found the 2 log cats

Comment: 05-14 10:27:15.083 22981-22981/com.karanvir.hhh E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.karanvir.hhh, PID: 22981
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.karanvir.hhh/com.karanvir.hhh.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference

Comment: I am willing to pay $20 for the answer

Comment: you'd be much more likely to receive help if you showed a screenshot of your code. we cant help if we cant see what we're trying to fix.